# Return Type of Library function exec_SELECTcountRows

Tags: php, sql, types, typo3

The Typo3 DB LIB has a method called `exec_SELECTcountRows`. The implementation looks like this:

```
/**
 * Counts the number of rows in a table.
 *
 * @param   string      $field: Name of the field to use in the 
                        COUNT() expression (e.g. '*')
 * @param   string      $table: Name of the table to count rows for
 * @param   string      $where: (optional) WHERE statement of the query
 * @return  mixed       Number of rows counter (integer) or 
                        false if something went wrong (boolean)
 */

public function exec_SELECTcountRows($field, $table, $where = '') {
    $count = FALSE;
    $resultSet = $this->exec_SELECTquery('COUNT(' . $field . ')', $table, $where);
    if ($resultSet !== FALSE) {
        list($count) = $this->sql_fetch_row($resultSet);
        $this->sql_free_result($resultSet);
    }
    return $count;
}
```

### Question:

Is the return type of `exec_SELECTcountRows` truly an integer or rather a string containing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're right. The PHPdoc differs from the behavior (as mysql functions return the value as string).

I filed a [bug report](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/29169), as I think this should be changed to return a true integer.

Comment: Well, what is the actual bug? Are you encountering a flaw because of that documentation issue? Are you actually having any problem?

Comment: Thx SK. So for now I need to add explicit casting if a "strongly-typed integer" is needed?

Comment: Exactly, you have to cast on your own

Answer (score 1):

PHP is loosely-typed, a string is an integer and vice-versa. It depends on context. I think truly that function's return-type will be changing depending on query and context.

For example the function can return `FALSE` which is a boolean.

As long as there is an actual database result to return, `count(*)` based columns are normally returned as string, not integer (with [MySQL Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)). So in that case the return-type is actually string, not integer. But as PHP is loosely typed, this does not make much of a difference.

**Mind the gap:**

That function can either return a string or `FALSE`. If you write a unit test, you should check the type as well and differ here.

The function has the mixed return type already documented, so assert first if it's returning FALSE or not.

Then if not returning false, assert the (int) value of the return value if you need to get the numerical integer value from the string.

Comment: Thx hakre. I am aware of the loosely-typed character of php. Unfortunately for me I does make a difference here. When I use the result of this function, for example in phpUnit, I got stated that: "value '2' (string) does not equal 2 (integer)" and the assertion fails. Same is true, when I use the result as a JSON response.

Comment: @SunnyRed: That differs on your assertion. And take care that you're not comparing 0 with FALSE when you cast to (int). `(int) FALSE` will be `0`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I prefer to change the function result rather than my assertions. Sure, depends. Regarding "false". I stick with the traditional -1 here. I hope this works out fine. Time hopefully will tell ;)